# Seeing what LaTeX passes to Lua and what Lua passes to LaTex

Tags: luatex

When writing code like

```
\documentclass{article}
\directlua{dofile("myLuaFunctions.lua")}
\newcommand*{\myFunction}[3]{%
    \directlua{tex.print(myFunction(#1, #2, #3))}%
}


\begin{document}
   \myFunction{3}{5}{7}
\end{document}
```

I'd like to see :

1. what Lua receives from LaTex
2. what (La)TeX receives back from Lua

Regarding 1.
I have read in http://cahiers.gutenberg.eu.org/cg-bin/article/CG_2010___54-55_13_0.pdf that it is enough to place this code at the beginning of the TeX file to see what Lua receives :

```
\newrite\luadebug
\immediate\openout\luadebug luadebug.lua
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\closeout\luadebug}
\newcommand\directluadebug{\immediate\write\luadebug}
```

but just placing it at the beginning of my TeX file gives me a compilation error. \newrite is not recognized. I have a message like unrecognized sequence ...

Regarding 2.
Is there a way to get the Lua written in the TeX document to see if it writes the expected string ?

Any other debugging tip is welcome, my understanding of the process being really limited.

Comment: `\newwrite` with two `w`  meaning :  "new" "write stream"

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you. Is there a way to see what is the Lua output, what does Lua writes into TeX?

Comment: I tend to ujust duplicate any `tex.print(....)` and put a print(....) on the line above so anything written back to tex is also written to the terminal, ot of course `\typeout{\directlua{....}}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle could you please show a full example in an answer? It is hard for me to imagine what you are saying in your last comment.

Comment: In fact I just used `\showtokens\expandafter{%` around my `\directlua` as suggested in here : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253706/is-it-possible-to-view-the-latex-code-after-lua-expansion-is-made and the Lua output is displayed in the compiler output.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle just the second part of my question is answered in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253706/is-it-possible-to-view-the-latex-code-after-lua-expansion-is-made.
The first part of the question which was to find how to see what Lua receives has been answered here.
I am telling in case you're the one who closed this one saying it is already answered there. Only partially in my opinion. The response to the first question is really interesting in my opinion.

Comment: sorry, I re-opened, do you want to self answer?

Answer (score 1):

What I now use (with the help of an article referenced in the question and a correction given in a comment plus the question referenced in another comment) is the following, even if not optimal :

Example of LaTeX file

```latex
\newwrite\luadebug
\immediate\openout\luadebug luadebug.lua
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\closeout\luadebug}
\newcommand\directluadebug{\immediate\write\luadebug}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox,graphicx,tikz}
\directlua{dofile("placeTextNode.lua")}
\newcommand*{\textNode}[2]{%
    % The following is added around \directlua to see Lua output into LaTeX
    % It allows you to see the Lua output but it breaks the compilation though.
    %\showtokens\expandafter{%
        % \directluadebug (command defined on top) instead of \directlua if I want to write in luadebug.lua file what is passed to Lua.
        % It modifies the final pdf output unfortunately and I have to put 
        % \directlua back when I want to generate my pdf
        \directlua{%
            tex.print(textNode("\luaescapestring{\unexpanded{#1}}", #2))
        }
    %}
}

\usepackage[paperwidth=120pt, paperheight=120pt, margin=10pt]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[boxsep=0pt, left=0pt, right=0pt, top=0pt, bottom=0pt, sharpish corners, opacityframe=0, opacityback=0, boxrule=0pt]
        \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt, y=1pt]
            \draw[line width=0mm, white] (0,0) -- (100,0) -- (100,100) -- (0, 100);
            \textNode{abc\\ def}{50}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

- where the first four lines define the \directluadebug that I use in place of \directlua according to the comment in the file above to see what Lua receives from LaTeX. Even though it alters/modifies the pdf output and I just use it and remove it.
- where I use `\showtokens\expandafter{...}` around the same \directlua to see what Lua writes into LaTeX, even though it breaks the compilation. The Lua output is written inside the compilation output and it is handy. The compilation is unfortunately broken even for proper LaTeX being written: even when commenting the `\showtokens\expandafter{...}` wrapper makes the compilation work again.

example of associated placeTextNode.lua

```lua
function textNode(t, x)
    return "\\draw[xshift=" .. plus30(x)  .. ", yshift=50, text width=20] node[draw, anchor=north west]{" .. t .. "};"
end

function plus30(x) 
    return x + 30
end
```

Don't hesitate to show, in a dedicated answer with full examples, what you do if you have better solutions. For example, an equivalent of `\directluadebug` that doesn't modify the behaviour or an equivalent of `\showtokens\expandafter{...}` that does not break the compilation.